# How to select records from a table with unique value of an attribute of the same table ? please answer it in regard of oracle sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
**consultant_id**  **c_specialty**
  001                cardiology
  002                cardiology
  003                surgery
```

from this table i am trying to select the consultant with unique specialty so only 003 should be selected.

Comment: i  have done this  much
select count(*),specialty
from consultant
group by specialty
having count(*)=1;
but the issue with that is i am unable to find a way to display the records from this table like the consultant's id who has the unique specialty.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: actually it's my first time using it i did want to write my solution which i have but failed to do so you can see i didn't even properly write the question someone edited it will be careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the c_specialty and get the ones where count = 1. Then filter your table on those specialty.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE c_specialty IN (
  SELECT c_specialty
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY c_specialty 
  HAVING COUNT(c_specialty) = 1)
```

Comment: thank you i got it didn't know you can use count in having clause without using it in select again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *
  from consultant 
  where consultant_id in (
    select min(consultant_id)
      from consultant 
      group by c_specialty
      having count(*) = 1
    );
```

Comment: no it's not working just showing all the records i guess you didn't understand the question i need to find the consultant with unique specialty i don't think your answer provides that.

Answer (score 0):

Select all rows where no other row with a different consultant but the  same specialty exists:

```
SELECT to.consultant_id,
       to.c_specialty
       FROM <your table> to
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM <your table> ti
                                WHERE ti.consultant_id <> to.consultant_id
                                      AND ti.c_specialty = to.c_specialty);
```

(Assuming `consultant_id` is unique. Replace `<your table>` with your actual table name.)

Comment: Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: @The Impaler: Missed a `,`. Fixed. (But it's still untested as no DDL and sample data as provided.).